# On some extra questions after the solution of a cauchy problem.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have the Cauchy problem

$$ \begin{cases}  y' = 2xy + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \\y(1) = 0 \end{cases} $$

I solved this problem and I obtain

$$y(x) = e^{x^2} \int_{1}^x e^{-t^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} dt $$

Now I am tasked in

1. finding the maximum domain in which this is defined and call it $I$
2. find $\lim_{x \rightarrow \inf(I)} y(x)$ and find  $\lim_{x \rightarrow \sup(I)} y(x)$
3. Given $f(x) = e ^{- x^2} y(x)$  find the cardinality of the set $\{f^{-1}(\lambda) \}$ where $\lambda \in f(I)$.

I think the answer to point three is that for all $\lambda$ the cardinality of the set $\{f^{-1}(\lambda) \}$  is one because $$e^{-t^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}> 0 \forall t$$

and so the integral function would be strictly increasing.

I am doubtful on the maximum domain though, how would I find the max domain? is $ 0$ a problem since I have $\sqrt{t}$ at the denominator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) boils down to: for which values of $\mathrm x$ is the integral convergent?

To avoid complex numbers and division by $0$, $\mathrm x$ must be greater than $0$. Making the change of variable $\mathrm{u=\sqrt t}$ we can turn the integral into (leaving out the constant factor of $2$)
$$\mathrm{
\int_1^{\sqrt x}{e^{-u^4}}\,du
}$$
Now we can compare the above integral for arbitrarily large values of $\mathrm x$ with the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral): 
$$
\mathrm{
\Big{|}\int_1^{\infty}{e^{-u^4}}\,du\Big{|}<\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{-u^2}}\,du={\sqrt\pi}
}$$
We can compare the integral for arbitrariliy small values of $\mathrm x$ (which are still greater than $0$) with the integral of unity:
$$\mathrm{
\Big{|}\int_1^0e^{-u^4}\,du\Big{|}<\int_0^11\,du=1
}$$
So we have $\mathrm{I=(0,\infty)}$.

> (2)

The integral is finite in the closure of $\mathrm I$. But $\mathrm{e^{x^2}}$ is unbounded in $\mathrm I$.
$$\mathrm{
\lim_{x\to\sup(I)}y(x)=\infty
}$$
According to [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) $$\mathrm{
\left\{\sum_{k=0}^n{(-u^4)^k\over k!}\right\}_n
}$$
converges uniformly to $\mathrm{e^{-u^4}}$ for $\mathrm{u\in[0,1]}$ which enables us to do the following maipulations.
$$\mathrm{
\int_0^1e^{-u^4}\,du=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\int_0^1{u^{4k}\over k!}\,dk=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{(-1)^k\over(4k+1)k!}:=K
}$$
And therefore
$$\mathrm{
\lim_{x\to \inf(I)}y(x)=-2K
}$$

> (3)

$$\mathrm{
f(x)=2\int_1^{\sqrt x}e^{-u^4}\,du\implies f'(x)={e^{-x^2}\over\sqrt x}>0\;\forall\;x\in I
}$$
Therefore $\mathrm{f}$ is strictly increasing and hence is injective in $I$. Consequently for $\mathrm{\lambda\in f(I)}$ there is a unique $\mathrm{x:f(x)=\lambda}$ i.e. $\mathrm{\#(f^{-1}(\lambda))=1}$.

Comment: Thank you Jack! everything is pretty clear as usual but unfortunately I have a couple of questions (as usual) :  why do you say "For the given ode to be real, x must be greater than 0"? and why is it that the first question boils down to convergence?

Comment: @Monolite You've got a ${1\over\sqrt x}$ in the diff eqn. The denominator can't be 0 and to avoid complex numbers we restrict ourselves to $x>0$. (1) explicitly states ''domain in which this is defined''. ''Defined'' here means finite. Suppose the integral were instead $\int_2^x{dt\over(t-1)^2}$ which diverges at $x=1$ then $I$ would be $(1,\infty)$. This integral also converges for $x\in(0,1)$ but $I$ has to be the maximum domain and '[domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_(mathematical_analysis))' here means an __interval__ i.e. $(0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$ would not work.